# Is there any offline safe method to prevent web-shell uploading in aspnet?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, security, file-upload

I have a simple page in asp net 5, and users can upload their images there. Valid files are: `*.jpg, *.png`, so I'm doing steps below to validating the files:

- Validating filename length : e.g: file name must be less than 50 alphabet characters
- Validating filename : replacing any hidden or invalid characters
- Validating file size : based on our configurations (e.g: less than 10MB)
- Validating file extensions : based on our white-list: `*.jpg, *.png`
- Validating `Mimetypes` : based on our white-list for `IMAGE/JPEG, IMAGE/PNG`
- Validating file's first bytes (`Magic Number`) : based on our white-list for `JPG: "FF-D8-FF-DB", "FF-D8-FF-E0" , "FF-D8-FF-EE"  ,"FF-D8-FF-E1"` and `PNG: "89-50-4E-47"`
- Uploading the file with a random (guid) filename in the temp folder outside webroot: without any executing permissions.
- Scanning the file with AV (Kaspersky or Norton Security) service installed.

But, some `webshells` can bypass these steps, like `Insomnia webshell` or others (they use the magic number headers at the first of file headers and inject their codes into some part of the file).

So my question is :
how can I detect and prevent `webshell` uploading?
Should I read and check the whole file for some black-list keywords?
Or what?

btw :We can't use any online `webshell` detection services.

This is a simple shell injected into a PNG file by woanware.co.uk:
[image]

Comment: If the file extension is validated as an image, what scenario do you envision something executing these files?

Comment: @NoahStahl The images are listing to all users in another page (i.e. Page2), so I doubted if the infected (uploaded web-shell-injected) file, can do something evil in the Page 2 or not:-?

Comment: My understanding of web shells is they need to be in a file location and with extension treated as executable. It doesn't seem like ASP.NET would attempt to execute a `.jpg` file.

Comment: The pattern I always use for user uploads to go directly to cloud storage like Azure Blobs, never to the web server. This way user provided files are never on your server.